# Как заменить DesiredCapabilities с ChromeOptions в Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, proxy

Мне необходимо импользовать `Selenium` с `proxy` для его конфигурации я использую `DesiredCapabilities` вот такоим образом:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8000");
proxy.setSslProxy("xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8000");
proxy.setSocksUsername("LOGIN");
proxy.setSocksPassword("PASS");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("proxy", proxy);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");

capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

И это работает, но проблема в том что перегрузка конструктора `ChromeDriver` принимающая `DesiredCapabilities` версии `Selenium 3.8.1` - `@Deprecated`. Если я правильно интерпретировал документацию, то на смену `DesiredCapabilities` пришел `ChromeOptions`.

Как при помощи `ChromeOptions`, или просто не используя `@Deprecated` конструкций сделать тоже самое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
// Add the WebDriver proxy capability.
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("myhttpproxy:3337");
options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);

// Add a ChromeDriver-specific capability.
options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

В твоём случае получается как-то так:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8000");
proxy.setSslProxy("xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8000");
proxy.setSocksUsername("LOGIN");
proxy.setSocksPassword("PASS");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
options.addArguments("start-maximized");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```